# How can I check the syntax of a Git mailmap file?

Tags: git, mailmap

How do I check the syntax of a Git mailmap file after adding/removing records? I want to make sure each line represents a valid [mapping](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog#_mapping_authors) and not some garbage.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the (sorted) list of the repo's authors with / without `.mailmap` with

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%aN %aE" | sort -u
```

and

```
git log --all --pretty=format:"%an %ae" | sort -u
```

The first list should be taking your `.mailmap` into account and transform names/e-mails (provided you've set your config right with `git config --global log.mailmap true`), while the other uses raw commit data.

Comment: I just  need to check if the file has valid syntax (with pointers to invalid lines, if any). How this approach would help?

Comment: Hmm, I might have misunderstood your needs, I thought you were trying to spot potentially remaining untransformed names/emails... but you're right, there should be an easier way to just do a formal syntax check.